# Partial mocking of class with void methods using Mockito

Tags: java, android, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following class:

```
public class A extends B {

    public A(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }   

    public void reg(Manager manager) {
        //some operations
    }    

    public void unreg(Manager manager) {
        manager.function1(this);   
    }   

    @Override   
    public void getData(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        t.function1();
        t.function2();
    }    

    T t;
}
```

Now, in this class I want to mock the getData method but not the other 2 methods. So, whenever getData gets called with context and intent, i want to execute my custom method. But for reg and unreg, I want to call the original function. Note that all have return data type as void.

I am a newbie to Mockito and java. I have written the following code:

```
    A mockA = Mockito.mock(A.class);
Manager mockMan = Mockito.mock(Manager.class);          
doCallRealMethod().when(mockA).register(eq(mockMan));
doCallRealMethod().when(mockA).unregister(eq(mockMan));
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Context getContextArg = (Context) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        Intent getIntentArg = (Intent) invocation.getArguments()[1];
        //mockgetData will be the function I want to call instead
        mockgetData(getContextArg,getIntentArg);
    }

}).when(mockA).getData(eq(getContext()),eq(new Intent()));
```

The problem that I'm facing here is that to mock getData I have to call some functions on object t which is set by the constructor. How can I use the value of the T object when the original constructor gets called whenever A class is instantiated.
I'm not sure whether I'm using doAnswer correctly here. Any help would be appreciated.